# Get reports automatically from SQL Server Reportings Services (SSRS) with powershell

Tags: powershell, command, ssrs-2008

I'm using our SQL Server Reporting Services to get the user ID's and corresponding PC names.
I'm wondering if there is way to get this reports faster by a PowerShell command?

Now I have to go to:

Home >  ConfigMgr_BNL > Hardware > General > Computers in a specific workgroup or domain

specify the domain and click on view report, afterwards I need to export it to a csv file each day..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just subscribe to the report. When you see the report tile, click the `...` on the top right of the tile and select "Subscribe". You can then schedule the report to run once a day and output the results to a file share in CSV format.

It's pretty self-explanatory but if you need more info, here is a link to the MS documentation on all this subscription based.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/subscriptions/subscriptions-and-delivery-reporting-services?view=sql-server-2016